# Can I determine if someone watched an embedded YouTube video with Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a video hosted on YouTube that I want to embed on a landing page. Is it possible that I tell who clicked on the video to watch / how long they watched it?

They would watch it right on the landing page; they wouldn't click the video and be re-directed to YouTube.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a specific user you're after, put the video on a link with a unique URL and video and send that to them. See if the view count in YouTube goes up.

If you'd like to see general, anonymous analytics, you can easily integrate Google Analytics with YouTube videos using [a number of methods](https://www.google.com/search?q=google+analytics+youtube+embedded) such as one by [Cutroni](http://cutroni.com/blog/2008/07/29/tracking-youttube-videos-with-google-analytics/) and another from [Loves Data](http://www.analyticsresults.com/2013/03/youtube-video-tracking-into-google.html) — albeit I haven't used either.

In short:

- Most of them append [event tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide) on the play button and other actions.

Alternatively, you could use [YouTube Analytics](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/).

Comment: I don't particularly like the specific user reply, as there is no guarantee that the specific view count increase was due to the user you sent the unique URL to.

Comment: @NRGdallas, if the URL is private, and the unlisted video on YouTube is not linked to from anywhere, then I'd say it's clear-cut

Comment: No, this video is listed elsewhere on my website; I wanted to use it in a landing page though to see if engagement goes up. I'll check out the 3 methods you suggest for general, anonymous analytics.

Comment: @MarkBubel, let me know how it goes

Comment: @MarkBubel, did either method work?